# Latency spikes regularly spaced on a OnePlus5 phone, reproducible on both ATT & TMobile

Tags: networking, internet, mobile-network

I'm seeing latency spikes consistently spaced. I'm using [packetlosstest.com](http://packetlosstest.com) to check latency (also experiencing the issue with real-time apps). Normal latency is ~100ms, at regular intervals I experience latency spikes from 2-5x (200-500ms latency).

I have not noticed this problem before today, the most recent change is that I added a 2nd ATT SIM, so I now have two SIM cards (ATT & TMobile). I experience the same result on both networks. A restart of the phone made no difference.

Since I can reproduce the problem on two networks, the problem seems likely to originate on the phone. Is this familiar to anyone?

The results of the latency test are shown in the accompanying image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Root cause identified: Having two sims in the phone causes the problem. When I removed the 2nd sim, no reboot even needed, the problem disappeared. Wow OnePlus, wow.

Comment: I would assume that the reason is that common dual-sim phone only have one radio. Therefore the radio control switches periodically between both SIM cards and of the seconds SIM card is active the first SIM can't send or receive anything which ends up in those latency spikes you have observed.

Comment: That's a very interesting observation, I appreciate it.